# How to access session of a php application via another laravel application which hosted in same domain?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I have a php application (Non Laravel) hosted on **domain.loc**.

I need to access the `session` data of that to `login` to another
application which is developed using Laravel and hosted in same domain (it's address is 'domain.loc/testing').

> domain.loc -- [Non Laravel App]
>
> domain.loc/testing -- [Laravel App]

Is there any possible way to access a session of non-laravel application in a laravel application without using `token-based`
authentication.

Or is there anyway where we can authenticate a laravel application via a  non-laravel application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `session_start()` at the beginning of the `index.php` file found in the `public` folder. This will "resume" the php session.

After that you can access the session using the php superglobal `$_SESSION['foo']` in your laravel app.

Comment: Thank you Angad. It worked. Does this affect Laravel session or can we use both without any issues?

Comment: @IsuruBuddhika This will not affect the Laravel session.